# Can you have a timer on an async filestream that only counts down when nothing is beeing received?

Tags: c#, timer, async-await, filestream

I'm using a basic file stream to read out a outputReportBuffer through the hid.dll.

As it is setup, i receive messages in real time and i display the data in my program.
Currently i am struggling to find a solution around a timer that should start the moment i stop receiving messages from the file stream.

Is there any trigger in the file stream it self that i can use to check whether or not there's still messages coming through?

```
try
{
    readTrigger = true;
    while (readTrigger)
    {
        await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, outputReportBuffer.Length);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

This is how I'm using the File stream and it has been working for me without any issues, until now where i need some sort of trigger/timer to see if if there's still messages coming through.

Any advice on how it could be done better or a pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pointless to include `catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}`.  It does nothing productive, it just clears the stack of the exception; you might as well just remove it anywhere you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadAsync` accepts a cancellation token.  You can pass in a token that will cancel itself after a set period of time.  If the task ends up being cancelled then you'll know that the read timed out and can respond accordingly.

Comment: Im aware that this is possible, but thats not what im looking for. As it stands there can be up to 10-15sec without any message coming through. im looking for a trigger, that tells me that there are currently no messages coming through. while its still trying to read. not timeout related

Comment: @wankr And if you use a new cancellation token every time you perform a read that's exactly what you'll get.